# Worauf bezieht sich dieser Satz aus dem Grimm-Märchen "Der Mond"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich zitiere mal:

> Vorzeiten gab es ein Land, wo die Nacht immer dunkel und der Himmel
>   wie ein schwarzes Tuch darüber gebreitet war, denn es ging dort
>   niemals der Mond auf, und kein Stern blinkte in der Finsternis. **Bei
>   Erschaffung der Welt hatte das nächtliche Licht ausgereicht.**

[Der Mond - Brüder Grimm](https://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_mond)

Leider verstehe ich den Zusammenhang nicht. Wieso war das nächtliche Licht ausreichend, wenn die Nacht da schon immer dunkel gewesen ist? Bezieht sich der Satz eventuell auf irgendwelche Sprüche aus der Bibel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not depend on the language or culture. Mythology.SE might be a good place, if translation is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei der Verfassung der Genesis war den Verfassern noch unbekannt, dass das Licht von der Sonne kommt, bzw. vom Mond.

Erst werden Erde und Himmel getrennt, dann Licht und Finsternis. Dann wird es einige Male Abend und Morgen, ein neuer Tag, aber am vierten Tag werden erst Sonne und Mond geschaffen. [Genesis](https://www.bibleserver.com/EU/1.Mose1) Dabei dürfte nächtliches Licht in Abhängigkeit von der Mondphase eigentlich keine schwierige Schlussfolgerung sein.

Auch dass es einen Ort geben kann, von dem aus der Mond nie sichtbar ist, ist eine phantastische Behauptung.

Die Grimms beziehen sich einerseits auf die Schöpfung, andererseits aber spinnen sie sich ihre eigene Geschichte zusammen, die einerseits noch viel abgedrehter ist, als der Mond am Baum aufgehängt wird z. B., andererseits erklären sie aber, dass das Licht vom Mond kommt.

> Bei Erschaffung der Welt hatte das nächtliche Licht ausgereicht.

Märchen arbeiten ja oft mit fiktiven Prämissen, auf die man sich nur einlässt, um der Geschichte zu folgen. Hier ist eine Prämisse, dass die Welt und das Land erschaffen wurden, eine zweite, dass das Licht damals ausgereicht hätte. Ob ausgereicht für die Erschaffung selbst oder für wie immer geartete Ureinwohner wird nicht gesagt.

Es entspricht aber der inversen Logik von Kreationisten, dass die komplexe Umwelt geschaffen wurde, damit der Mensch darin leben kann; statt zu erkennen, dass die Umwelt begrenzt hat, was sich in ihr entwickeln konnte. Darwin publizierte sein Werk aber ohnehin erst lange nach den grimmschen Märchen.

Das heliozentrische Weltbild war aber bereits etabliert.

Da von Ureinwohnern weiter nicht die Rede ist, und wieso diesen nächtliches Licht ausgereicht hat, deren Nachfahren aber nicht mehr, neige ich dazu anzunehmen, dass das nächtliche Licht gereicht hat, um das Land in seinen Details zu erschaffen, nachdem es Himmel getrennt war. Diese, wenn auch widersinnige Prämisse, kommt besser ohne weitere Erklärung aus und mag geeignet gewesen sein, naive Zweifel zu beruhigen, auch weil sie an bereits Geglaubtes, Widersinniges anschließt (die Genesis).

In der Folge wird es aber immer unphysikalischer, etwa dass der Mond im Baum hängt, was schon dessen Lauf über den Nachthimmel widerspricht, als auch der Beobachtung, dass von unterschiedlichen Blickwinkeln der Mond mal kurzfristig in einem Baum zu hängen scheinen mag, aus einem anderen jedoch links daneben, einem wieder anderen rechts daneben.

Die Semantik des Textes bleibt es aber, Erklärungen mit religiöser Verbrämung zu liefern, nämlich für unterschiedliche Mondphasen von Voll- bis Neumond.

Comment: Die Grimms haben Märchen nur gesammelt, nicht selbst erfunden. Das darf man nicht verwechseln; hast du an einer Stelle aber, "Die Grimms beziehen sicn ..."--nein, tuhn se nich.

Comment: Das ist mir bekannt, aber m.W. haben sie ihre Quellen nicht ausgewiesen, und mit eigenen Worten erzählt. Insofern haben sie sich die Geschichten ein Stück weit zu eigen gemacht und beziehen sich dann als Erzähler, wenn auch nicht als Erfinder, auf etwas. Welche Formulierung würdest Du vorschlagen?

Comment: "*Auch dass es einen Ort geben kann, von dem aus der Mond nie sichtbar ist, ist eine phantastische Behauptung.*" - Warte noch ein paar hundert Millionen Jahre, dann wird es für die Hälfte der Erdoberfläche gelten *gg*

Answer (score 7):

Ich habe die Geschichte gelesen. Und in meinen Augen ist der fett markierte Satz schlicht die Erklärung, WARUM kein Mond und kein Stern blinkte:

Das nächtliche Licht war bei Erschaffung der Welt genug gewesen, deshalb brauchte man (der Schöpfer, Gott) weder Sterne noch Mond.

Es ist -soweit ich das sehen kann- keine Referenz auf irgendeine andere Geschichte, sondern steht komplett für sich alleine.

Comment: Da bietet sich die Frage an: wo kam denn dieses nächtliche Licht anfänglich bei Erschaffung der Welt her, wenn es weder Mond noch Sterne gegeben haben sollte? Ist das vielleicht als "göttliches Licht" zu betrachten?

Comment: Sehr gute Frage, die ich leider nicht beantworten kann aus den mir zur Verfügung stehenden Quellen.

Comment: @ðulfiqaːr wenn man abseits von künstlichem Licht in einer bewölkten Nacht unterwegs ist, kann man trotzdem seine Umgebung zumindest teilweise erkennen, Umrisse von Büschen oder Steinen, z.B. . In einer mondhellen Nacht wäre es einfacher, aber zur Not geht's auch ohne... Ich denke, dieses "Restlicht" ist hier gemeint - keine offensichtliche Lichtquelle, aber trotzdem ist Orientierung möglich.

Comment: @Arsak: Dieses Restlich ohne Sonne, Mond und künstliches Licht - wo kommt es denn her? Bewölkt ist es auch noch, also selbst von den Sternen kommt es nicht. Und wieso "Restlicht" in Anführungsstrichen?

Comment: @userunknown ich würde mal auf Streuung des Mondlichts tippen (Wolken sind ja nicht lichtundurchlässig, auch wenn sie ab und an dicht genug sind, dass der Mensch Sonne/Mond nicht erkennen kann - gibt ja auch Tage, an denen man die Sonne nicht sieht, trotzdem ist es hell), aber das ist wohl eher eine Frage für die Physiker. Die Anführungsstriche, damit keiner auf die Idee kommt, das wäre der offizielle Fachterminus (falls es einen gibt), da müsste ich erst nachschlagen.

Comment: Ohne Mond gibt es auch kein Streulicht vom Mond und die Sterne sind auch bei leichter Bevölkung zu schwach, um noch was zu sehen. Man kann dann nichts mehr erkennen. Selbst bei Wolkenlosigkeit reicht m.W. das Sternenlicht nicht, um etwas anderes als die Sterne selbst zu sehen.

Comment: @userunknown: dem kann ich aus eigener Erfahrung widersprechen. Mit genügeng Akkomodationszeit liegt für mich in einer sternenklaren aber mondlosen Nacht zwischen auf einer offenen Wiese sehe ich wo ich hinlaufe und im dichten belaubten Wald (z.B. ein Buchenwald) -> ganz finster.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica: In einer sternenklaren Nacht, bei Arsaik war es aber eine bewölkte Nacht.

Comment: @userunknown: ich bezog mich auf "Selbst bei Wolkenlosigkeit reicht m.W. das Sternenlicht nicht, um etwas anderes als die Sterne selbst zu sehen" - ist aber eher off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Man sollte auch einen Fehler nicht ausschließen. Plausibler wäre der Satz

> Bei Erschaffung der Welt hatte das nächtliche Licht nicht ausgereicht.

D.h. es konnte nicht die ganze Welt mit Mond- und Sternenlicht versorgt werden und es gab "ein Land, wo die Nacht immer dunkel und der Himmel wie ein schwarzes Tuch darüber gebreitet war".

In der Tat liefert eine Google-Suche nach diesem Text Treffer, u.a.
[diesen](https://books.google.de/books?id=D3J3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT575&lpg=PT575&dq=Bei+Erschaffung+der+Welt+hatte+das+n%C3%A4chtliche+Licht+nicht+ausgereicht) und [diesen](https://jakoble.blogspot.com/2014/10/wie-fugt-sich.html).

Ich habe keinen Zugang zu den Originaltexten der Brüder Grimm, aber es wäre sinnvoll, das zu prüfen. Erstmalig erscheint das Märchen in der 4. Auflage von 1840. Selbst wenn es in der Urfassung tatsächlich "hatte das nächtliche Licht ausgereicht" heißt, könnte es sich dennoch um einen Fehler der Grimms beim Aufschreiben oder um eine irrtümliche Auslassung in der zugrundeliegenden mündlichen Erzählung handeln.

Das alles ist natürlich spekulativ. Auch die Bibel trägt nichts Brauchbares zu diesem Satz bei. Bezüge zur Genesis sind jedenfalls genauso spekulativ wie meine Vermutung.

Meiner Meinung nach hat das Märchen insgesamt den Charakter von Nonsensliteratur. Es scheint aber eine (kindgerechte?) Erklärung der vier primären Mondphasen des Mondzyklus vom Vollmond zum Neumond zu enthalten:

> Die vier versorgten den Mond mit Öl, putzten den Docht und erhielten wöchentlich ihren Taler. Aber sie wurden alte Greise, und als der eine erkrankte und seinen Tod voraussah, verordnete er, daß der vierte Teil des Mondes als sein Eigentum ihm mit in das Grab sollte gegeben werden. Als er gestorben war, stieg der Schultheiß auf den Baum und schnitt mit der Heckenschere ein Viertel ab, das in den Sarg gelegt ward. Das Licht des Mondes nahm ab, aber noch nicht merklich. Als der zweite starb, ward ihm das zweite Viertel mitgegeben, und das Licht minderte sich. Noch schwächer ward es nach dem Tod des dritten, der gleichfalls seinen Teil mitnahm, und als der vierte ins Grab kam, trat die alte Finsternis wieder ein.

Warum aber ging der Mond dann wieder auf? Hier die Erklärung:

> Als aber die Teile des Monds in der Unterwelt sich wieder vereinigten, so wurden dort, wo immer Dunkelheit geherrscht hatte, die Toten unruhig und erwachten aus ihrem Schlaf.

Der erneute Mondaufgang nach Neumond wird dann Petrus zugeschrieben:

> Da brachte er die Toten zur Ruhe, hieß sie sich wieder in ihre Gräber legen und nahm den Mond mit fort, den er oben am Himmel aufhing.

Answer (score 1):

Auch in der Bibel wird in Genesis Himmel und Erde vor dem Licht erschaffen, das scheidet als Erklärung aus.

In dem Märchen geht es aber um eine andere Zeit und einen anderen Ort, nämlich das besagte Land. Der fett markierte Satz hat damit wenig zu tun, so dass meine Verständnisfrage wäre, warum der Satz überhaupt da steht.

Comment: Es wird auch ständig Abend und Morgen, ein neuer Tag, aber Sonne und Mond werden erst am 4. Tag erschaffen. Die Einsicht in natürliche Zusammenhänge war noch erstaunlich schwach.

Comment: In der Tat gibt es Übersetzungen ins Englische, in denen der Satz weggelassen  wurde - wahrscheinlich,weil er sehr unklar ist. Beispiel: https://www.longlongtimeago.com/once-upon-a-time/fairytales/grimms-fairytales/the-moon-der-mond/

Comment: @userunknown Das ist eine Frage der Interpretation, vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6pfungsgeschichte_(Priesterschrift). Zitat: Sonntag: Tag und Nacht (Gen 1,4–5) Auf das Schöpferwort hin ist Licht eingeflutet und hat die Vorwelt „in einen trüben Dämmerzustand versetzt.“ Gott scheidet das Urlicht vom Chaosdunkel.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist übrigens nicht völlig aus der Luft gegriffen. Es gibt die Theorie, dass auf der Urerde durch das Bombardement von Meteroren so viel Wasser verdampfte, dass eine geschlossene Wolkendecke die Erde bedeckte und daher nachts kein Licht auf die Erdoberfläche gelangen konnte.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Flutlicht und Dämmerzustand sind 2 Bilder, die nicht recht zusammenpassen. 1954 ist auch zu spät für die Grimms. b) Das Licht wird Tag und die Finsternis Nacht genannt (1. Tag) und Sonne/Mond kommen erst am 3. Tag. Die Erdrotation macht aber Tag und Nacht. Ohne Sonne braucht es für Finsternis keine Wolken, aber von mir aus zitiere auch E.v.Däniken um das zu retten. Ich kann übrigens weder Hebräisch, noch Griechisch oder Latein, um die Originalquellen zu interpretieren.

Comment: @userunknown Da haben wir Gemeinsamkeiten. Hebräisch und Griechisch kann ich auch auch nicht, und ich schließe daraus, dass wir beide kein Theologiestudium absolviert haben. Und ich vermute, dass wir beide die BIbel nicht als Quelle naturwissenschaftlicher Erkenntnis betrachten. Mein Kommentar sollte auch nur darauf hinweisen, dass der Schöpfungsbericht der Genesis vage,  aber nicht völlig absurd ist. Wenn wir hypothetisch davon ausgehen, dass die Erde lange von einer geschlossenen Wolkenschicht bedeckt war, so gab es Hell-Dunkle-Zyklen (Licht = Tag, Finsternis = Nacht).

Comment: Nachts konnten weder Mond noch Sterne die Wolkenschicht durchdringen, tags war es hell, aber diffus. Erst nach dem Aufklaren wurden Sonne, Mond und Sterne sichtbar. "Dann sprach Gott: Lichter sollen am Himmelsgewölbe sein, um Tag und Nacht zu scheiden." Aber egal, ob die Genesis und die wissenschaftlichen Erkenntnisse zur Urerde zusammenpassen oder nicht: Ich sehe keine Korrelation mit dem strittigen Satz der Märchens.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Ich verstehe die Argumentation nicht. Ja, wir gehen beide davon aus, dass die Bibel keine natwi. Darstellung ist. Dennoch versuchst Du die Erdgeschichte auf eine Weise zu beschreiben, die sie mit der Schöpfungsgeschichte in Einklang bringen soll. Für wen? Für die Mondgeschichte sicher nicht, denn da ist es ja nur ein Ort (auf der Erde, wohl), der kein Mondlicht hat. Da führt die Argumentation also nicht hin. Meinst Du, als die Erde entstand als eigenständiger, rotierender Körper gleich die Meteoriten eingeschlagen sind. Und woher kam das Licht geflutet? Wozu die Spekulationen?

Comment: @userunknown Da wir uns eigentlich weitgehend einig sind, sollten wir die Dikussion beenden.